# Декоратор на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача: реализовать декоратор `@contract`. Смотри файл `contract.py`

Требования:

1. Необходимо проверять типы аргументов и тип выходного значения функции. Указываем кортеж типов для `arg_types`. Каждый тип в кортеже - соответсвует типу аргумента. Для типа выходного значения - указываем `return_type`

   ```py
   @contract(arg_types=(int, int), return_type=int)
   def add_two_numbers(first, second):
       return first + second

   add_two_numbers(1, 2)  # ok
   ```
2. Если передан неправильный тип, вызываем ошибку `ContractError`:

   ```py
   add_two_numbers('a', 'b')  # raises ContractError
   ```
3. Можно не передавать какое-то значение из `arg_types` или `return_type`. Или передать значение `None`: тогда ничего не будет происходить. Пример:

   ```py
   @contract(return_type=int)  # validates only return type, args are ignored

   @contract(return_type=None, arg_types=None)  # validation is disabled

   @contract(arg_types=(str, str))  # return type check is disabled
   ```
4. Можно передать специальное значение `Any` для того, чтобы игнорировать какой-то один тип внутри `arg_types`. Например:

   ```py
   @contract(arg_types=(int, Any))
   def add_two_numbers(first, second):
       return first + second

   add_two_numbers(1, 2)  # ok
   add_two_numbers(1, 3.4)  # ok
   add_two_numbers(2.1, 1)  # raises ContractError
   ```
5. Параметр `raises` отвечает за типы исключений, которые функция может кидать. Если выкинутое исключение отсутсвует в списке разрешенных, то мы добавляем `ContractError` (смотри `raise from`). Пример:

   ```py
   @contract(arg_types=(int, int), return_type=float, raises=(ZeroDivisionError,))
   def div(first, second):
       return first / second

   div(1, 2)  # ok
   div(1, 0)  # raises ZeroDisionError
   div(1, None)  # raises ContractError from TypeError
   ```

Файл contract.py

```
class ContractError(Exception):
    """We use this error when someone breaks our contract."""


#: Special value, that indicates that validation for this type is not required.
Any = object()


def contract(arg_types=None, return_type=None):
    ...  # TODO: implement
```

---

Я пробовал сделать первый пункт задачи данным путем, но я даже его не смог пробить, что говорить о следующих пунктах.. Помогите пожалуйста реализовать данную задачу, я не понимаю что необходимо сделать тут, примеров в интернете не могу найти вот и обращаюсь на прямую к специалистам :(((

Я только учусь, всю голову себе сломал этой задачей

```
class ContractError(Exception):
    """We use this error when someone breaks our contract."""


#: Special value, that indicates that validation for this type is not required.
Any = object()


def contract(arg_types=None, return_type=None):
    def inner(function, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Args', args, kwargs)
        result = function(*args, **kwargs)
        print('Result',result)
        return result
    return inner

@contract(arg_types=(int, int), return_type=int)
def add_two_numbers(first, second):
    print(type(first),type(second))
    return first + second

add_two_numbers(1, 2)  # ok
```

Answer (score 1):

Может быть примерно так. Для первого пункта. И дальше по аналогии.

```py
def contract(arg_types, return_type):
    def actual_decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for idx, exp_type in enumerate(arg_types):
                if (exp_type != type(args[idx])):
                    raise AttributeError("Must be int")
            if (type(func(*args, **kwargs)) != return_type):
                raise AttributeError("Must be int")
            return 'ok'
        return wrapper

    return actual_decorator


@contract(arg_types=(int, int), return_type=int)
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

print(add(2, 2.5)) # Exception
print(add(2, 2))   #ok
```